# c++ return same Object to the caller

Tags: c++, destructor

I have the following code,

```
    ---file1.cpp---
    file1::file1()
{
    std::cout<<"Inside constructor \n";
}
file1::~file1()
{
    std::cout<<"Inside destructor \n";
}


---file2.cpp---
//file2 is a singleton. There is a single object instance available at anytime.
 file1 file2::cFunction()
{
    file1 f1();
    return f1;
}

----mainFile.cpp----
int main()
{
file2 o1;
file2 o2;
file1 obj1 = o1.cFunction();
file1 obj2 = o2.cFunction();
return 0;

}
```

The header files define the classes in file1.h and file2.h(again file2 is a singleton) and i have included them as required.(did not copy those things here).

So my requirement is like this, when I call o1.cFunction() , it creates a file1 object and returns it to obj1(as a copy). Instead I want a single object created and returned to obj1.

Right now, o1.cFunction() would print,
Inside COnstructor  //from cFunction
Inside Destructor   //from cFunction
Inside Destructor   //from main

I need only one call to the destructor to be made.

Comment: Look up move constructors.

Comment: I suppose (N)RVO should take care about it.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is allowed to elide the copy of `f1` in

```
file1 file2::cFunction()
{
    file1 f1;
    return f1;
}
```

This is an allowed optimization and not required behaviour. However, the standard also specifies that if the compiler chooses not to do copy elision when it could, it has to bind the value being returned to the move constructor first(even if it isn't an rvalue). This will ensure that you get a move of `f1` at least. In other words, the code you have already does what you want it do. Note that all of this is assuming C++11. It doesn't hold for C++03 or earlier.

Comment: unfortunatley the project is not in c++11

Comment: `file f1(1)` declares a function, not instantiating an object (most vexing parse).

Answer (score 0):

Your request is something that compilers *can* do as an optimization, but there is no way to force them to do it.

In general, your line `file1 obj1 = o1.cFunction();` might immediately print 2 destructors (`f1`, plus the return value), with a third destructor call when `obj1` goes out of scope.

If you want to prevent copies, then you will have to use a different pattern than returning the object by value.  For example, `cFunction` could fill out an argument received by reference; or you could return a pointer to a `new`'d object (preferably managing this with `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`).